# How to change widget update period at create time?

Tags: android, widget, broadcast

In android docs it says :

> If you would like the user to configure settings when they add a new App Widget, you can create an App Widget configuration Activity. This Activity will be automatically launched by the App Widget host and allows the user to configure available settings for the App Widget at create-time, such as the App Widget color, size, update period or other functionality settings.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets#Configuring

But there is no example to change the widget period at create time with configuration Activity. Is it possible? If it is, how to change the widget refresh period on create time?

Thank you for reading this
Any help is appreciated